# Any way to self-host plugins and update them like wp-hosted plugins does?

Tags: plugins

I have developed a WordPress plugin. Now, is it possible to just have it stored on my own web server and then the plugin has any functionality where it check if there is a newer version on my server and then make it looks exactly as when any other plugin has a new update?

Comment: No, if you publish your plugin in the plugin repository you can't do this. What if you publish a clean plugin, but add malware to it in the next update? And user can't scan it before installation since it's self hosted.

Comment: The question specifically says "stored on my own web server" so it wouldn't be hosted in the plugin repository. And the answer to the question is yes. I do this with my self-hosted (actually gitlab) plugins and themes.

Comment: @Nathan Johnson How?